# HTML form not submitted with laravel

Tags: jquery, html, forms, laravel

I make a form, when page is loaded the form is hide at the end of page, when the specific button click the clone of form is show into the div in section and when the clone of form is submitted. its not submitted.
I check when original form is submitted its work fine. but not its work with clone form. how to submit it.
HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
 <h1 class="text-center margin-top10 fsize60"></h1>

 <section class="text-center replace-section">

 </section>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#frm_infradi_result").click().clone().removeClass('hide').addClass('show').prependTo( ".replace-section");
});
</script>

<div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-3 animated fadeInRight animation-delay-5 hide" id="frm_infradi_result">
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h3 class="h2 ur no-margin-padding" style="display: inline;">
            انفرادى مکتب نتائج برائے سال 1437ھ
        </h3>
        <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {{--{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'url'=>route('result')]) !!}--}}
                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'url'=>'mailto:itsoftsaeed@gmail.com']) !!}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-2">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="font400" style="font-size: 1.5em">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">
                                <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check-circle"></i></span>بنات
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-1">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="font400" style="font-size: 1.5em">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">
                                <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check-circle"></i></span>بنين
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-2">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="font400" style="font-size: 1.5em">
                                <input type="radio" name="Examtype" value="S">
                                <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check-circle"></i></span>ضمنی
                            </label>
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-1">
                        <div class="radio">
                            &nbsp;
                            <label class="font400" style="font-size: 1.5em">
                                <input type="radio" name="Examtype" value="A">
                                <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check-circle"></i></span>  <span>سالانہ</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-push-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="course" class="form-control select-adjust pointer rtl padding014 fsize26">
                                <option value="04">متوسطہ</option>
                                <option value="05" selected="selected">ثانويہ عامہ</option>
                                <option value="06">ثانويہ خاصہ</option>
                                <option value="07">عاليہ</option>
                                <option value="08">عالميہ </option>
                                <option value="09">عالميہ سال اول</option>
                                <option value="10">دراسات سال اول</option>
                                <option value="11">دراسات سال دوم</option>
                                <option value="13">تجويد للحفاظ</option>
                                <option value="14">تجويد للعلماء</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-push-2">
                        {!! Form::label('lblcourse', 'متعلقہ درجہ کا انتخاب',['style'=>'font-size: 1.5em;', 'class'=>'font400' ]) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-push-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::text('rolno', null, ['class' => 'form-control text-center fsize26','maxlength'=>'5']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-push-2">
                    {!! Form::label('lblrolno', 'طالب علم/طلبہ کا رول نمبر',['style'=>'font-size: 1.3em;', 'class'=>'font400']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-push-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::submit('تلاش کریں۔ ', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-ar btn-info']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it from the `$(document).ready`

```
<script>

$(document).on('click','#frm_infradi_result', function(){
  $(this).clone().removeClass('hide').addClass('show').prependTo( ".replace-section")
});

</script>
```

Comment: no, the problem is same, The problem is that everything working fine but the clone is not submit the form why ?